# Adding image in Array Item - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

### How to add a image in array item (that will be pushed to Autocomplete) with JavaScript / jQuery?

Hello, I'm trying to learn JS by myself and I'm having a lot of issues. Now I will just explain one of them.

I have jQuery Autocomplete in one text input, I want to display a message when don't have the autocomplete results. Now I just show a message (working), but I want to add a GIF loading image.

---

### **My code:**

```
$("input[type=search]").autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: function(request, response) {
                    populate(request.term, response);

                    result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(result, request.term)

                    // Just prevent to add a lot of "loading" itens to result.
                    for (var i in result){
                        if (i.item.type == "loading"){
                            result.splice(i, 1);
                        }

                        var item = {};
                        item.type = 'loading'
                        item.label = "Loading.."
                        item.value = "Loading.."
                        result.push(item)
                    }
                    response(result)
                }
```

---

What can I do to display a GIF with this code?

-------**Edit:**
Now I tested the code (this code is a new one) and it's appear don't work. What can be the problem?

Comment: where is the path for gif image..i dont see any .gif extension

Comment: yes, you're right... but you can't see the .gif path because I don't know how I can insert the image inside the item. That's the point. :/

Comment: @OPUS Yes, but I don't know a lot of ajax.

Comment: so you bring this data to be displayed using ajax and want to show  that data in dropdown with images?are you getting your data successfully?

Comment: No, I just show one item with image: "Loading". I want display a loading gif image to "Loading" item in autocomplete result. 

I can't do something like item.value = "<img src="" class=""> Loading..."; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make sure the code in the source part is correct.This is just a basic module about how to go about things.

```
 $("input[type=search]").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
        populate(request.term, response);
        //your stuff
    }.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li />")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><img src='" + your - path + "' />" + your value + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Comment: Wow, amazing code. But I'm getting one error on console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined

Comment: I think we're getting closer, don't leave me now!! hahahah

Comment: @FernandoPaladini:look,you need to learn some basic jquery,ajax for this..its an error and needs to be solved...you have written your code..understand it and solve it...from the info you have given ..its not possible to get any solution..next time when you post some question,ensure that you ask question properly..you might get downvoted if people think you have not researched.This Happens to everybody..time to grab a book or practice some more code..

Comment: I just change .data("autocomplete") to .data("ui-autocomplete"). Can you edit your answer with this information? if you do that, I'll give you the best answer. Thanks.